# Append Data from Access DB to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, append

I currently have an Access Database with a table named "orders". I need to append the records from the Access table "orders" to an existing table also named "orders" in SQL Server.

Both databases are not linked, but both are on the same machine, Windows Server 2008R2.

How do I write the query?

Again, in SQL Server, I already an existing table named "orders" with some data in it, which I need to keep. I need to append from Access to this existing table in SQL Server.

Also, all the fields are identical, named the same in both tables.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append data from an Access table to a SQL server table via a pass-through query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951475/how-to-append-data-from-an-access-table-to-a-sql-server-table-via-a-pass-through)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would link the SQL Server table into the Access database (it will automatically be named `Orders1` or so), and run an Access INSERT query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Orders1
SELECT * FROM Orders
```

assuming that the columns are really identical, and there is no IDENTITY column in the server table. Otherwise, specify the columns.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you